# What's a good way to log data in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm a new Emacs user, and I'm trying to find a good way to track various bits of information I'm interested in: how long I sleep each night, how far I run, what books I read, etc. Is there a good mode to handle this, and to keep the data in a usable form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/)  The big daddy of note takers / organizers.  People are known to
flock to Emacs just to use org-mode

Comment: I'm just starting to get familiar with `org-mode`. Is there a particular set of functions within org-mode that would be particularly useful for this?